# Process to monitor incoming emails and then send a summary (bodies of certain emails) as one email

Tags: email

Hi there this is my first question so apologies in advance if the information I provide is vague or of no use to answer.

Basically I need a program that can:

1. Monitor emails arriving in Microsoft Outlook
2. When an email from a certain address is received its body is copied into a new email (which is not sent yet)
3. Monitoring continues for a further 5 minutes and all other emails from that address (if any) are also added to the above email
4. After the time is up the email is sent to a certain email address

Thanks for the help in advance and I will provide as much info as I can if i've left out anything important!

Comment: I guess you need to develop a custom plugin. OKInbox does something like what you want, but isn't even close. What are your means and/or skills? If you can program yourself, try sharpdevelop in combination with Netoffice, to develop a plugin.

Comment: This appears to be a feature specification, not a programming question.